# Is there an alternative to IntrabundleParallelization in Dataflow 2.1.0?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

According to release notes of dataflow 2.X, IntraBundleParallelization is removed. Is there a way to control/increase parallelism of DoFns on dataflow 2.1.0 ?

I was getting better performance when I used IntrabundleParallelization on 1.9.0 version of dataflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed because its implementation keeps a handle on the `ProcessContext` of a `ProcessElement` call after the call completes, and this is unsafe and not guaranteed to work.

However, I agree that it was a useful abstraction, and it is unfortunate that we don't have a replacement yet.

As a workaround, you can try the following:

- In your DoFn's `@Setup`, create an `Executor` with the needed number of threads
- In your DoFn's `@StartBundle`, create an `ExecutorCompletionService` wrapping the executor
- In `@ProcessElement`, submit a `Future` to it representing the result of processing the element
- In `@ProcessElement`, also `poll()` the `CompletionService` for completed futures and output their results
- In `@FinishBundle`, wait for all remaining futures to complete, output their results, and shut down the `CompletionService`.

Remember to *not* use the `ProcessContext` in your futures. `ProcessContext` can only be used from the current thread and from within the current `ProcessElement` call.