# IntraBundleParallelization in Apache Beam Python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Does the Python SDK for Apache Beam have [IntraBundleParallelization](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/IntraBundleParallelization) support like the Java SDK? I realize that the benefit of multithreading in Python is limited, but I was wondering if there were any efforts or plans to add support to do the same with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntraBundleParallelization was removed from Dataflow Java SDK 2.X.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2#individual_api_changes

The reason was mentioned in another post:
[Is there an alternative to IntrabundleParallelization in Dataflow 2.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023871)

It is not likely to be added to Python SDK any time in the future.