# Google Dataflow's worker are almost idle because of slow IO calls

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are creating pipeline using google dataflow. One of our cases is to call an 3rd party service to persist the data there.

The problem is that this 3rd party service is slow ( save is quite complicated ), but it can handle many, concurrent connections.

We found out, that if we create in ParDo a ThreadPoolExectutor(100) and make async calls instead of sync calls, we can save a lot more data per second. But this approach is not good.

What would be a good approach using Dataflow? Obviously we could run Dataflow with 100 workers instead, but this is not very cheap solution - especially when each worker utilises 5% CPU.

Do you have any ideas for me? We thought about using PubSub for this service, but it will complicate our solution quite a lot.

In direct runner there is a [targetParallelism](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/direct-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/direct/DirectOptions.java#L58) parameter, is there something similar in dataflow runner?

Comment: Or maybe, dataflow is handling threaded processing by itself, and my pipeline is badly configured.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023871/is-there-an-alternative-to-intrabundleparallelization-in-dataflow-2-1-0 which probably is my case. It's not beautiful however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative to IntrabundleParallelization in Dataflow 2.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023871/is-there-an-alternative-to-intrabundleparallelization-in-dataflow-2-1-0)